# Laravel accessing pivot table name field in a Many to Many relation

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table

I am retrieving the latest 4 rows from my Sermon table and passing it to a view with View Composer. but i don't know how i can access the tags attached to each sermons

```
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;
use App\Sermon;
use App\Tags;

use Illuminate\View\View;

class SermonComposer
{
public function compose(View $view)
{

    $sermons = Sermon::take(4)->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();


    $view->with('sermons', $sermons );


}
```

}

How can I access the name of the tags related to a single sermon?
a sermon could have multiple Tags

this is what i have in my Sermon model

```
public function tag()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
}
```

this is my blade

```
 @foreach ($sermons as $sermon )
            <tr>
                <td>{{$sermon->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$sermon->title}}</td>

                <td>{{$sermon->pivot->name}}</td>
                <td><img src="{{ asset('img/sermons/'. $sermon->sermon_image)}}" alt=""></td>
                <td><a href="#">@include('svg.edit')</a></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

if i {{dd($sermons)}} this is what i get and i noticed my relations array is empty

[image]

Comment: show your relation with tags in your question.

Comment: If you setup correct relations you may use `$sermon->pivot->xxx`

Comment: in my blade or my view composer file ?

Comment: show your Sermon Model

Comment: and show blade view where you are trying to access $sermons if possible it will help us to help you

Comment: @CYBERSIX at this line `<td>{{$sermon->pivot->name}}</td>` in your loop you are trying to access `tags`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's many to many relationship so you should use a plural name as relation like

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
}
```

After defining relation you have to eagar load your tags while querying using `with()`.

```
public function compose(View $view)
{

    $sermons = Sermon::with('tags')->take(4)->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();

    $view->with('sermons', $sermons );

}
```

And after that in blade view, you can do like this

```
@foreach ($sermons as $sermon )
        <tr>
            <td>{{$sermon->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$sermon->title}}</td>
            @foreach ($sermon->tags as $tag )
            <td>{{$tag->name}}</td>
            @endforeach
            <td><img src="{{ asset('img/sermons/'. $sermon->sermon_image)}}" alt=""></td>
            <td><a href="#">@include('svg.edit')</a></td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

> This is just example I am giving your problem may be different. Show the blade view if you want the more specific answer.

If you have any doubts, please comment.

Comment: Property [tags] does not exist on this collection instance. i get this error now but my relations array is not empty anymore

Comment: have you changed relation to plurar `tags`?

Comment: at this line `<td>{{$sermon->pivot->name}}</td>` in your loop you are trying to access tags?

Comment: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: I am not getting where you are getting errors can you specify more? by the way i have updated answer. please tell me where you are accessing tags and where is error.

Comment: I don't even know what happened by now its working .. thanks a bunch

Comment: @CYBERSIX Great.